# Simple Linear Dependency

Tags: python, numpy, math, scipy, statistics

Trying to find if two vectors are linear dependent or independent.  I keep coming across the error "last two dimensions of an array must be a square?  Can someone explain please?

```
def Indy2Vec(v1, v2):
    
    A = np.array([v1])
    B = np.array([v2])
    print(A)
    #A =np.linalg.matrix_rank(A)
    A=np.linalg.solve(A,B)
    
    return A


v1 = np.array([0, 5, 0])
v2 = np.array([0, -10, 0])
v3 = np.array([1, 2, 3])
v4 = np.array([-2, -4, -6])
Indy2Vec(v1,v2)
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you are expecting still solve to do here. Please explain

Comment: Thank you, good point.  I guess it should return True if it is linear dependent and false if it is not.

Comment: Wouldn't simple division with a mask tell you that?

Comment: Yes division would work but I have to do it this way.  Sorry was a bit confused last night.  Have to learn this on my own.  I think what I was looking for was the (v1*v2) *(v1*v2)T.  Or to square the matrix.  It took me awhile to get my mind straight.  Thank You.  @MadPhysicist

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Bad problem statement

It seems you are not solving the right problem. Stated as you did, it cannot work as the [method](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.solve.html) you are using:

> Computes the “exact” solution, x, of the well-determined, i.e., full
> rank, linear matrix equation ax = b.

As defined in documentation.

It is tempting to write your problem as `Ax = b`. But then you need a 3x3 matrix to test against a vector `b=[0,0,0]T` and find a non trivial solution `x` to claim all three vectors are not linearly independent. But then it will mean the matrix does not have a full rank.

In your code, the following expression fails to fulfil the function signature:

```
np.linalg.solve(np.array([v1]), v2)
```

And raises the following error:

```
LinAlgError: Last 2 dimensions of the array must be square
```

A valid call to `numpy.linalg.solve` in term of matrix shapes would be:

```
np.linalg.solve(np.array([v1, v2, v3]).T, np.zeros(v1.size))
```

But fails in two ways:

```
LinAlgError: Singular matrix
```

First because the matrix is not full rank and therefore not invertible. Secondly this does not solve the problem for two vectors.

### General solutions

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import linalg
```

Instead you want to solve a more general problem about [linear independence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_independence) which can be solved either by **assessing the [rank](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank_(linear_algebra))** of `[v1, v2]T`:

> In linear algebra, the rank of a matrix A is the
> dimension of the vector space generated (or spanned) by its
> columns. This corresponds to the maximal number of linearly
> independent columns of A.

With numpy, you can do so using [numpy.linalg.matrix_rank](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.matrix_rank.html):

```
np.linalg.matrix_rank(np.array([v1, v2]).T) # Missing dimension: 1
np.linalg.matrix_rank(np.array([v1, v3]).T) # Full rank: 2
```

This method counts null Singular Values computed performing the [SVD decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value_decomposition), an implementation of this algorithm is provided by [scipy.linalg.svd](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.linalg.svd.html):

```
U, s, V = linalg.svd(np.array([v1, v2]).T) # s = [11.18033989, 0.]
U, s, V = linalg.svd(np.array([v1, v3]).T) # s = [5.55992016, 2.84381571]
```

Or **performing the [Gauss Elimination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_elimination)** (let's say using [LU decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LU_decomposition)) of it and inspecting the results. Package scipy provides the [scipy.linalg.lu](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.linalg.lu.html):

```
p, l, u = linalg.lu(np.array([v1, v2]).T) # Null pivot: u = [[5., -10.], [0., 0.]]
p, l, u = linalg.lu(np.array([v1, v3]).T) # Full rank:  u = [[5., 2.], [0., 3.]]
```

All this methods assess the number of dimensions of the vector space spanned from the columns of your matrix. If the matrix is full rank then your vectors are linearly independent. If it is not, they there are at least two dependent vectors.

Then a simple way to solve your problem is:

```
def indep1(*args):
    A = np.array(args).T
    return np.linalg.matrix_rank(A) == len(args)

indep1(v1, v2) # False
indep1(v1, v3) # True
indep1(v1, v2, v3) # False
indep1(v1, np.zeros(v1.size)) # False
```

### Special case

If you stays in 3D vector space and just needs to check against two vectors, you can also take advantage of [cross product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product) as provided by [numpy.cross](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.cross.html):

```
np.cross(v1, v2) # Colinear: [0, 0, 0]
np.cross(v1, v3) # Not colinear: [15,  0, -5]
```

A more specific alternative would be:

```
def indep2(a, b):
    return not np.allclose(np.cross(a, b), 0.)

indep2(v1, v2) # False
indep2(v1, v3) # True
# indep2(v1, v2, v3) # TypeError
indep2(v1, np.zeros(v1.size)) # False
```

### Constant ratio

As suggested by `@MadPhycist`, we can also assess the fact than colinear vectors share a scalar scale factor such `a = k*b`, then a non bullet proof way to test it is to check if the ratio of coordinates is constant:

```
def indep3(a, b):
    r = a/b                                 # Ratio of coordinates
    q = np.isfinite(r)                      # Filter bad ratio (zero division)
    return not np.allclose(r[q], r[q][0])   # Assess all ratio are equal

indep3(v1, v2) # False
indep3(v1, v3) # True
# indep3(v3, np.zeros(v1.size)) # IndexError
```

If it requires less computation than previous solutions and does not rely on high level of linear algebra, it needs to handle specific cases and the suggested implementation is smelly (don't use it).

### Gramian method

The method exposed by `@dmuir` can safely be implemented for two vectors as follow:

```
def indep4(a, b):
    return not np.isclose(np.dot(a,b)*np.dot(b,a), np.dot(a,a)*np.dot(b,b))

indep4(v1, v2) # False
indep4(v1, v3) # True
indep4(v3, v4) # False
indep4(v3, np.zeros(v1.size)) # False
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple test for two vectors is:
A and B are linearly dependent iff

```
(A.B)*(A.B) == (A.A) * (B.B)
```

where . is the dot product.

Of course when using floating point arithmetic you have to be careful with testing equality.

This can be generalized to more vectors. V[1] .. V[n] are linearly dependent iff their Gramian G is singular, where

```
G[i,j] = V[i].V[j] (i,j=1..N)
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not using a much simpler algorithm:

```
def is_linearly_dependent(a, b):
    non_zero = b != 0
    if len(np.unique(a[non_zero]/b[non_zero])) > 1:
        return False
    else:
        zero = np.logical_not(b)
        if np.any(a[zero] != 0):
            return False
    return True
```

Comment: Are you sure your function behaves properly with float types? Taking unique value of float is risky and may behave unexpectedly. In general never test float for equality use epsilon ball test instead.

Comment: I tested it on arrays of float type too, and it works. However, I agree, your point is completely valid.

Comment: Notice your algorithm is not symmetrical: `False == f(0,v) != f(v,0) == True`. And off course it fails to cope with float arithmetic inaccuracies depending on the vector `f(v1, v1+eps) == True` or `f(v2, v2+eps) == False`.

Comment: I don't get these results
```
is_linearly_dependent(np.array([1,2,3]), np.array([1.0, 2.0, 3.0])) = True

is_linearly_dependent(np.array([1,2,3]), np.array([1.0, 2.0, 3.0])+1e-10) = False

is_linearly_dependent(np.array([0,2,3]), np.array([0.0, 4.0, 6.0])) = True

is_linearly_dependent(np.array([0,0,3]), np.array([0.0, 4.0, 6.0])) = False
```
of course it is assumed both `a` and `b` are one dimensional numpy arrays.

Comment: Well I did have this result for a lot of vectors. You can see it with trial vector OP created. Just test it with eps=machine precision. What is you machine precision? Did you checked the non symmetric behaviour with zero as well?

Comment: You are not seeing it because you are not checking case which are problematic.

Comment: pretty sure machine precision is `1e-16`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222728/discussion-between-jlandercy-and-amir).

Comment: we concluded that the algorithm above has some problems with corner cases that include zero.